# getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nullpointer exception raises when i click on the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080994/nullpointer-exception-raises-when-i-click-on-the-button)

```
case R.id.Button01check:
            startActivity(new Intent (SaveData.this,CheckData.class));
            break;
```

this is my CheckData.java

```
 public class CheckData extends ListActivity  {     
TextView selection;
DataManipulator dm;
private DataManipulator DataManipulator;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.check);
    dm = new DataManipulator(this);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    DataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);

    Certificates testCertificates = new Certificates(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE));

    DataManipulator.open();
    DataManipulator.createCertificatesEntry( (Certificates) testCertificates);
    DataManipulator.close(); 

    testCertificates = null;

    DataManipulator.open();
    testCertificates = DataManipulator.getFirstCertificatesFromDB();
    DataManipulator.close();

    image.setImageBitmap(((Certificates) testCertificates).getBitmap());

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

}
this is line 29 **DataManipulator.createCertificatesEntry( (Certificates) testCertificates);**

this is my DataManipulator.java

```
    public class DataManipulator {
public static final String KEY_IMG = "image";

 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBtest";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CERTIFICATES_TABLE = "certificates";

    private static final String CREATE_CERTIFICATES_TABLE = "create table "+CERTIFICATES_TABLE+" (" +KEY_IMG+" blob not null) ";

    private final Context mCtx;
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CERTIFICATES_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CERTIFICATES_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    public void Reset() { mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1); }

    public DataManipulator(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    }

    public DataManipulator open() throws SQLException {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() { mDbHelper.close(); }

    public void createCertificatesEntry(Certificates certificates) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        certificates.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_IMG, out.toByteArray());
        mDb.insert(CERTIFICATES_TABLE,  null, cv);
    }
    public Certificates getFirstCertificatesFromDB() throws SQLException {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CERTIFICATES_TABLE,  new String[] {KEY_IMG}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMG));
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            cur.close();
            return new Certificates(bitmap);
        }
        cur.close();
        return null;
    }    
}
```

this is line 60         **certificates.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);**

this is my logcat output

```
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{list.certificates/list.certificates.CheckData}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at list.certificates.DataManipulator.createCertificatesEntry(DataManipulator.java:60)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at list.certificates.CheckData.onCreate(CheckData.java:29)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
06-04 11:09:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case...all I can say either your `certificates` variable or `certificates.getBitmap()` api is returning null.

```
Certificates testCertificates = new Certificates(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE));
```

In above code [`decodeFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) needs the complete path to the image. What you passing is not a complete path to the file. So from the above two cases `certificates.getBitmap()` is most probable cause of the exception. [Context.STORAGE_SERVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#STORAGE_SERVICE) is not the full path to image.

Once you have the Uri for the image. Use the below code to get the image:

```
Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

Certificates testCertificates = new Certificates(bmp);

DataManipulator.open();
DataManipulator.createCertificatesEntry( (Certificates) testCertificates);
DataManipulator.close();
```

Ref:

[Images MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri%29)

Comment: updated my whole code once check it out...

Comment: i am selecting image from gallery and saving it to database

Comment: may be but the code i put in the ans is not picking file from the gallery. It is just passing the wrong path value.

Comment: ok but is there any other way to do it

Comment: Add a button to your screen, which user will click to browse for image. Move the code above to the handler of the image browse button. Once you have the file name, use that. Thats all I can say, there is no short ans.

Comment: if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
    mImageCaptureUri = data.getData(); 
    path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery   this is the path which i select images from gallery

Comment: i have added a button which picks images from gallery or sdcard

Comment: Just use the uri to get the Bitmap like `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` to load the bitmap from uri.